# SQL Update statement Database modify

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Table 1: Schema for the bookworm database. Primary keys are underlined. There are some foreign key references to link the tables together; you can make use of these with natural joins.

```
Author(aid, alastname, afirstname, acountry, aborn, adied).
Book(bid, btitle, pid, bdate, bpages, bprice).
City(cid, cname, cstate, ccountry).
Publisher(pid, pname).
Author_Book(aid, bid).
Publisher_City(pid, cid).
```

I need to reduce the prices of all of Charles Dickens’s books by 20 percent, using only one update statement.

Tried using...

```
update book
set bprice=bprice * .2
where alastname = 'Dickens';
```

but no luck, I get the syntax:

```
ERROR:  column "alastname" does not exist
LINE 3: where alastname = 'Dickens';
```

Not sure how to use subselects or 'nested select queries' to find the primary keys of the tuples that I need to update.

Comment: Since DML is not standardized, identify your intended RDBMS. Also read up on JOINs.

Comment: @PM77-1 Its just basic PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple join query would be this -

```
update Book set bprice = bprice * 0.8 where bid IN (select bid from Author_Book ab join Author a on ab.aid = a.aid where a.alastname = 'Dickens');
```

Note that you have to reduce by 20%, not make it 20%.

Comment: thank you for the response, I'm still learning how to implement join and you've shed some light on the topic for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update book b 
set bprice=bprice * 0.2 
where bid in (
 select aid, bid from Author a 
 inner join Author_Book ab ON a.aid = ab.aid where alastname = 'Dickens'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like the following statement. 
Please look for error messages.

```
update book b
set b.bprice=b.bprice * .2
where b.id in(select ab.bid from author_book ab join author a on a.aid = ab.aid where alastname = 'Dickens') ;
```